# How to change font for t= in node rmeter for the whole document (circuitikz)

Tags: fonts, circuitikz

Is it possible to change font for t= in node rmeter for the whole document. My goal is an instrument like in the lower part, but setting font and size with \ctikzset.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{instruments/scale=0.5}
\draw (0,0) to[rmeterwa, t=V](2,0);
\draw[yshift=-1cm] (0,0) to[rmeterwa, t={ \small \texttt{V}}](2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to define a new style `ta` and use `ta=`.

```
\ctikzset{
ta/.style={t={\small \texttt{#1}}},
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{instruments/scale=0.5,
ta/.style={t={\small \texttt{#1}}},
}
\draw (0,0) to[rmeterwa, ta=V](2,0);
\draw[yshift=-1cm] (0,0) to[rmeterwa, t={ \small \texttt{V}}](2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

#### OR

Alternatively use `t=` itself after setting

```
\ctikzset{
    t/.code={\ctikzsetvalof{bipoles/twoport/text}{\small\texttt{#1}}}
}
```

This MWE produces same output

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{instruments/scale=0.5,
    t/.code={\ctikzsetvalof{bipoles/twoport/text}{\small\texttt{#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[rmeterwa, t=V](2,0);
\draw[yshift=-1cm] (0,0) to[rmeterwa, t={ \small \texttt{V}}](2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```